# Javascript label in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below to populate a select box but I don't know how to add a label inside the select box.

At the moment, the select box is displayed as

```
Select Location
  California
  Florida
  Madrid
```

How do I add a label in between?

The result should be

```
Select Location
USA (label)
  California
  Florida
Spain (label)
  Madrid
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Javascript as below.

```
var map;

var markerData= [
    {lat: 36.4 , lng: -120.9  , zoom: 7 , name: "California"},
    {lat: 28 , lng: -81  , zoom: 7 , name: "Florida"},
    {lat: 40.39 , lng: -3.67  , zoom: 8 , name: "Madrid"},
];

function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: {lat: 2.432054, lng: 106.995850}
        });
        markerData.forEach(function(data) {
            var newmarker= new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position:{lat:data.lat, lng:data.lng},
                title: data.name
            });
            jQuery("#selectlocation").append('<option value="'+[data.lat, data.lng,data.zoom].join('|')+'">'+data.name+'</option>');
        });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

jQuery(document).on('change','#selectlocation',function() {
    var latlngzoom = jQuery(this).val().split('|');
    var newzoom = 1*latlngzoom[2],
    newlat = 1*latlngzoom[0],
    newlng = 1*latlngzoom[1];
    map.setZoom(newzoom);
    map.setCenter({lat:newlat, lng:newlng});
});
```

Select box is as below.

```
<select id="selectlocation" class="btn btn-default btn-select btn-select-light">
    <option class="btn-select-value" value="">Select Location</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And how do you expect JavaScript to understand, or appreciate, in which country a given city is located in order to provide the appropriate 'label'? Though I'd point you towards the [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) element as a suggestion.

Comment: You should look into `<optgroup>` elements for HTML - but you will still have to know where to put them.

Answer (score 2):

Making a group value variable `markerData` declare as follows you  option group label.

```
var markerData= {
    USA    :[
        {lat: 36.4 , lng: -120.9  , zoom: 7 , name: "California"},
        {lat: 28 , lng: -81  , zoom: 7 , name: "Florida"}
    ],
    Madrid :[
        {lat: 40.39 , lng: -3.67  , zoom: 8 , name: "Madrid"}
    ]
};
```

And add group value to the select option group Following way :

```
var $select = $('#selectlocation');
    $.each(opt, function(key, value){
        var group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '" />');
        $.each(value, function(){
            $('<option />').html(this.name).appendTo(group);
        });
        group.appendTo($select);
    });
```

**Example :**

```js
var opt = {
    USA :[
        {lat: 36.4 , lng: -120.9  , zoom: 7 , name: "California"},
        {lat: 28 , lng: -81  , zoom: 7 , name: "Florida"},
    ],
    Madrid:[
        {lat: 40.39 , lng: -3.67  , zoom: 8 , name: "Madrid"}
    ]
};

$(function(){
    var $select = $('#selectlocation');
    $.each(opt, function(key, value){
        var group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '" />');
        $.each(value, function(){
            $('<option />').html(this.name).appendTo(group);
        });
        group.appendTo($select);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectlocation" class="btn btn-default btn-select btn-select-light">
    <option class="btn-select-value" value="">Select Location</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is done with the [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) html element, but there is no magic, automated way to do this - you need to build the HTML yourself.

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="USA">
    <option>California</option>
    <option>Florida</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Spain">
    <option>Madrid</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```